# Long computations on Meteor

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, meteor, nonblocking

I learned that in Node.js you `yield` in between long computations to prevent the server from blocking. How do you achieve this on Meteor? Are there techniques for also doing this on the client?

I am new to web development, simple examples would be appreciated.

Comment: If you have a really long and cpu heavy computation, you might be interesting into putting it off to a separate process/service

Answer (score 2):

Meteor uses Fibers which behave a little different than usual Node.js code. I believe there's no need to yield manually. Instead, you may want to use `this.ublock()` method on the server side – see [this](http://meteorhacks.com/understanding-meteor-wait-time-and-this-unblock.html) awesome article that explains it in details.

If you're doing something really heavy on the client side (like calculating Mandelbrot set), split the execution with defers:

```
_.defer(function() {
  doSomethingQuiteLong();
  _.defer(function() {
    doSomethingQuiteLongAgain();
    ...
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is something interesting:

"In Meteor, your server code runs in a single thread per request, not in the asynchronous callback style typical of Node. We find the linear execution model a better fit for the typical server code in a Meteor application." -http://docs.meteor.com/#structuringyourapp

It seems there is no need to worry about the node.js limitation. But what does this mean then?