# Using Meteor, how to handle computationally intensive tasks?

Tags: meteor

Since Meteor is single threaded I would like avoid a pretty intensive function from bogging down my application. But, how would I go about this? I need the function to be able to access my database and take a parameter or two (an array). How would I do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23147250/2848483 Seems to show that there is not much to do as it doesn't follow the Node.js model.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `this.unblock()` as detailed [here](http://meteorhacks.com/understanding-meteor-wait-time-and-this-unblock.html), or you can create another meteor app that observes the mongoDB for relevant changes and does the computations there.

Answer (score 0):

Create the intensive function as a seperate application. Using [Meteor job collection](https://github.com/vsivsi/meteor-job-collection) the worker app can be written in Meteor or plain Node.js, scaled on as many workers as you need and communicate with your main app.